# Count characters/sms using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I count characters using [NobleCount](http://tpgblog.com/noblecount/) and the following code:

```
$('#message').NobleCount('#messageInfo',{
            max_chars: getMaxChars(),
            on_negative: function(t_obj, char_area, c_settings, char_rem){

            }
});
```

I want a feature like counting SMS, if the limit is reached the next 160 chars are for the second sms and so on. I can use parameters like on_update, on_positive, on_negative and block_negative.

I tried something using modulo but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want a solution using this plugin, or a more generic jQuery solution? This wouldn't be at all difficult on its own, but working it into an unknown plugin could be harder!

Comment: I just found this plugin for counting chars, but I also need to count the sms, so I appreciate any solution

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Firstly, character counting is very easy.  You just need to use the `length` property on a string.  To count the number of SMS messages needed, you'll need to divide by 160 and round up (because 161 characters requires 2 messages).  Your code should probably look something like this:

HTML:

```
<textarea name="message" value="" id="message"></textarea>
<p>
    <span id="remaining">160 characters remaining</span>
    <span id="messages">1 message(s)</span>
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
        $messages = $remaining.next();

    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        var chars = this.value.length,
            messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
            remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

        $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
        $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
    });
});
```

[See jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/nkuBa/)

Comment: Cool script @lonesomeday. What might this script look like if you needed to include the character count of a 'subject' textbox? The 160 character limit for SMS also takes into consideration the Subject. And also, is there a way to prevent typing in the textarea once the 160 character limit is hit, rather than having it spill over into a 2nd message?

Comment: Nice script @lonesomeday. I found if you clear the textbox, the characters remaining and number of messages were both set to 0. To overcome this, I added the following before the setting of the remaining and messages text property:
`if (chars == 0) 
{
  remaining = 160;
  messages = 1;
}`

Comment: If your message uses other characters, it can instead be encoded using UCS-2 (like UTF-16 but only BMP), for a limit of 70 characters. How can I do this?

Comment: Dividing by 160 is wrong: for concatenated messages, 6 bytes of the payload are taken up by a header (that allows the messages to be reassembled in the right order etc). Since there are only 140 bytes for the payload in total, and since each character takes 7 bits, that means you only get 153 characters per SMS when concatenating. [This page](http://mobiletidings.com/2009/02/18/combining-sms-messages/) explains the details.

Answer (score 46):

Beware that SMS is more complicated than you seem to indicate.

Standard "160-character" SMS uses a [strange 7-bit encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7_bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38) that covers most ASCII, some European accents, misc symbols such as €, some capital Greek letters (the ones that don't look like Roman characters).

If your message uses other characters, it can instead be encoded as Unicode using UCS-2 (like UTF-16 but only BMP), for a limit of 70 characters. Actually, the specification *says* UCS-2, but emoji (non-BMP Unicode) can be sent in SMS so that implies UTF-16 *is* being used, in which case each emoji must "use up" 2 characters out of the 70 total.

But some languages can use ["national language shift tables"](http://www.nowsms.com/shift-tables-national-language-sms-in-160-characters-without-unicode) which use an *alternative* 7-bit encoding. Most notably Turkish, but also Spanish, Portuguese, and ten Indian sub-continent languages. These are relatively new additions to the standard.

Even in the 7-bit encoding, a few characters are "escaped" which means they "use up" 2 characters. In the default 7-bit encoding, these are: `{}[]\|^~€`.

If your message goes beyond 160 characters, it can use "concatenated SMS", but then a small header is added to each message, meaning each segment only has room for something like 153 characters. There are two different versions of that header, of different sizes, thus it may not be 153 characters, but 152 (from memory). Similarly for Unicode concatenated SMS, the small header makes it 67 characters per segment.

Good luck with all that!

Comment: `function getSmsLength(v) {
    return v.replace(/([{}\[\]\\|\^~€])/g, "\\$1").replace(/\n/g, "--").length
} `

Answer (score 16):

Here is small plugin for you. It is my first jQuery plugin i give it for free ;)
you just need to start it with:

```
$('#smsText').smsArea();
```

The HTML:

```
 <b id="smsCount"></b> SMS (<b id="smsLength"></b>) Characters left
 <textarea id="smsText"></textarea>
```

The Javascript (updated 18.8.2014):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

    var
    e = this,
    cutStrLength = 0,

    s = $.extend({

        cut: true,
        maxSmsNum: 3,
        interval: 400,

        counters: {
            message: $('#smsCount'),
            character: $('#smsLength')
        },

        lengths: {
            ascii: [160, 306, 459],
            unicode: [70, 134, 201]
        }
    }, options);


    e.keyup(function(){

        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

            var
            smsType,
            smsLength = 0,
            smsCount = -1,
            charsLeft = 0,
            text = e.val(),
            isUnicode = false;

            for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                switch(text[charPos]){
                    case "\n": 
                    case "[":
                    case "]":
                    case "\\":
                    case "^":
                    case "{":
                    case "}":
                    case "|":
                    case "€":
                        smsLength += 2;
                    break;

                    default:
                        smsLength += 1;
                }


                if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€") isUnicode = true;
            }

            if(isUnicode){
                smsType = s.lengths.unicode;

            }else{
                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;
            }

            for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                    smsCount = sCount + 1;
                    charsLeft = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                    break
                }
            }

            if(s.cut) e.val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
            smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);

            s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
            s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);

        }, s.interval)
    }).keyup()
}}(jQuery));
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/t32h0gj4/1/

NOTE: there are some basic options

```
$('#smsText').smsArea({cut:false}); //Do not cut the SMS
$('#smsText').smsArea({maxSmsNum:2}); //2 SMS Max
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks for sharing! Exactly what I was looking for. A note: The line "smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = 3, charsLeft = 0);" is superfluous...

Comment: if you use cut:false in options you will see why this line is there

Comment: Thanks for sharing this wonderful solution and plugin. But I'm trying to use it with Asp.net while I'm trying to call it using a asp textarea then it is not working only with HTML textarea it is working. Could you please suggest me on that? Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with 'asp textarea' can you check what kind of events this textarea supports

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly.

Comment: `£` is counted as 92 characters. Also, there seems to be other errors in the script. Good base to build on though.

Comment: £ is not counted as 92 characters. It is an unicode character. So, 1 sms = 70 chars and remaining chars will be 68 which is correctly calculated. Excellent plugin by the way @sulest

Answer (score 3):

Once the message has been decoded as Craig McQueen stated in a this thread post and you have your actual character count, to count the needed SMS amount the following is enough:

```
function cntsms(len){ return len<=0? 0: (len>160? Math.ceil(len/153): 1); }
```

...I like one-row solutions so much.

Comment: Great function! But to take into account that the first sms is 160 characters long (not 153) for calculations on the 2nd, 3rd ... sms, it should be: 

function cntsms(len){ return len<=0? 0: (len>160? Math.ceil((len-7)/153): 1); }

(Can't get the code formatting to work properly. Neither backtick or indenting by four works...)

Comment: @aanders77 warning: when the message exceeds the 160 7-bits char limit EVERY segment of the message has a maximum length of 153 7-bits chars, because 7 are reserved for concatenation out of 160. So the first segment is 153 chars long too, making valid the function I posted. [This](http://www.nowsms.com/long-sms-text-messages-and-the-160-character-limit) as reference.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following script can produce more accurate calculation of SMS parts:

```
//field: a text box that contains the SMS Text
//cntField: a text box that will contain the remaining count of characters for each part
//smsCntfield: a text box that will contain the count of parts
//lang: 0 for English, 2 for Arabic
//maxLimit: Maximum count of characters to limit the TextBox, (ex: for 5 SMS in Arabic 331, in English 762
function textCounter(field, cntfield, smsCntfield, lang, maxlimit) {

    part1Count = 0;
    part2Count = 0;
    part3Count = 0;
    part4Count = 0;
    part5Count = 0;
    if (lang == 2) {
        // Arabic
        part1Count = 70;
        part2Count = 63;
        part3Count = 66;
        part4Count = 66;
        part5Count = 66;
    } else if (lang == 0) {
        // English
        part1Count = 160;
        part2Count = 145;
        part3Count = 152;
        part4Count = 152;
        part5Count = 152;
    }

    smsCount = 0;
    smsCharCnt = 0;
    smsTotalCount = 0;

    if (field.value.length <= part1Count) {
        smsCount = 1;
        smsCharCnt = part1Count;
        smsTotalCount = part1Count;
    } else if (field.value.length <= (part1Count + part2Count)) { 
        smsCount = 2;
        smsCharCnt = part2Count;
        smsTotalCount = (part1Count+part2Count);
    } else if (field.value.length <= (part1Count+part2Count+part3Count)) {
        smsCount = 3;
        smsCharCnt = part3Count;
        smsTotalCount = (part1Count+part2Count+part3Count);
    } else if (field.value.length <= (part1Count+part2Count+part3Count+part4Count)) { 
        smsCount = 4;
        smsCharCnt = part4Count;
        smsTotalCount = (part1Count+part2Count+part3Count+part4Count);
    } else if (field.value.length <= (part1Count+part2Count+part3Count+part4Count+part5Count)) { 
        smsCount = 5;
        smsCharCnt = part5Count;
        smsTotalCount = (part1Count+part2Count+part3Count+part4Count+part5Count);
    }

    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
        // if too long...trim it!
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    } else {
        cntfield.value = smsTotalCount - field.value.length;
        smsCntfield.value = smsCount;
    }

}
```

example use:

```
<html:textarea cols="30" rows="5" property="textEn"
                                                    title="Text English"
                                                    onkeydown="textCounter(document.form.textEn,document.form.remLen2,document.form.smsCount2,0,762)"
                                                    onkeyup="textCounter(document.form.textEn,document.form.remLen2,document.form.smsCount2,0,762)" />
                                                                                                <br>
                                                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="remLen2"
                                                    size="3" maxlength="3" value="160"
                                                    title="Char Count">

                                                (
                                                <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="smsCount2"
                                                    size="1" maxlength="1" value="1"
                                                    title="SMS Parts' />">
                                                )
```

Answer (score 2):

Every character from the extension table (GSM Extended Alphabet) is represented by two characters the actual maximum length is dynamically calculated as: 160 - k, where k is the number of extended characters used in the message.

You also have to consider the message length is 153 characters when concatenating messages with a 8bit reference number.

Unicode length is 70 characters, while concatenated 63 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the problems here, I try to write better solution. Adopted from several best answer here.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    part1Count = 160;
    part2Count = 145;
    part3Count = 152;

    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        var chars = $(this).val().length;
            messages = 0;
            remaining = 0;
            total = 0;
        if (chars <= part1Count) {
            messages = 1;
            remaining = part1Count - chars;
        } else if (chars <= (part1Count + part2Count)) { 
            messages = 2;
            remaining = part1Count + part2Count - chars;
        } else if (chars > (part1Count + part2Count)) { 
            moreM = Math.ceil((chars - part1Count - part2Count) / part3Count) ;
            remaining = part1Count + part2Count + (moreM * part3Count) - chars;
            messages = 2 + moreM;
        }
        $('#remaining').text(remaining);
        $('#messages').text(messages);
        $('#total').text(chars);
        if (remaining > 1) $('.cplural').show();
            else $('.cplural').hide();
        if (messages > 1) $('.mplural').show();
            else $('.mplural').hide();
        if (chars > 1) $('.tplural').show();
            else $('.tplural').hide();
    });
    $('#message').keyup();
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="message" value="" id="message"></textarea>
<div>
    <div><span id="remaining">160</span>&nbsp;Character<span class="cplural">s</span> Remaining</div>
    <div>Total&nbsp;<span id="messages">1</span>&nbsp;Message<span class="mplural">s</span>&nbsp;<span id="total">0</span>&nbsp;Character<span class="tplural">s</span></div>
</div>
```

You can get the code here http://www.mindrestingplace.com/2012/07/18/sms-character-counter/

Hope this will solve your problems.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I updated the script (for my purposes) to include the subject in the count as well. This is what I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
    $messages = $remaining.next();

$('#message').keyup(function(){
    var chars = this.value.length + document.getElementById('subject').value.length,
        messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
        remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

    $remaining.text(remaining);
    //$remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
    //$messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
});

$('#subject').keyup(function(){
    var chars = this.value.length + document.getElementById('message').value.length,
        messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
        remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

    $remaining.text(remaining);
    //$remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
    //$messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
});
```

});

I tested and it works. I also change the html a bit:

```
<p>
<span id="remaining">160</span> characters remaining
<!--<span id="messages">1 message(s)</span>-->
</p>
```

Comment: Now I would like to figure a way to prevent keystrokes in the form once 160 chars is reached. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is late to the game, but here's what I'm currently putting together.

The character limit is set to 459 to allow for concatenated messages (as set by my service provider), with a text unit tot-up per 160 characters used. Bear in mind this aspect is incomplete as each unit after the initial one would comprise of less than the 160 character template due to message headers and whatnot. I just havent gotten the exact breakdown from the provider yet.

The crucial difference in this script is that the character count is sensitive to non-standard GSM characters, their ascii values specified in the included array. Where a non-standard character is typed, the count is 2, otherwise 1.

```
$('#sms-message').keyup(function(){
var     chars = $(this).val(),
        arr_chars = chars.split(''),
        remaining = $('#remaining'),
        messages = $('#messages'),
        count = 0;

    $.each(arr_chars, function(i, l){
        var     ascii = l.charCodeAt(0),
                ascii_val = parseInt(ascii),
                //array of special chars
                arr = [13, 47, 92, 123, 124, 125, 126, 128];

        if($.inArray(ascii_val, arr) !== -1) { count = count + 2; }
        else { count = count + 1; }
    });

            //inaccurate count, will have to be finetuned to provider specs
    var     units = Math.ceil(count / 160),
            remaining_chars = 459 - count;

        remaining.text(remaining_chars + ' characters remaining');
        messages.text(units + ' text unit(s)');

        if(remaining_chars < 0) {
            $(remaining).css('color', 'red');
        }
        else {
            $(remaining).css('color', 'black');
        }
});
```

Comment: I know this comment's getting on in age now, but was just refactoring some old code and broke out some JavaScript that looks *very* much like your comment here. I hope you don't mind, but it's been extended a bit and wrapped up in a jQuery plugin at https://github.com/texh/jquery-smscharcount
Happy to give attribution / credit where it's due, and also to take it down if you'd rather that.

Comment: @Sunny Fame at last :)

Answer (score 0):

## For SMS sending character count

Logic / Requirement :

1. if len <= 160 than send (1 SMS)
2. if len > 160 and after every 153 character/len, than send (1++)

Use case :

3. len 1 to 160   = SMS send 1
4. len 161 to 313 = SMS send 2
5. len 314 to 466 = SMS send 3

And so on...

#### Script :

```
function cntsms(len) { 
   return len <= 0 ? 0 : ( len > 160 ? Math.ceil((len-7)/153) : 1);
}
```

Comment: This ignores every complexity of sending SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function() {        
          $('#message').keydown(function() {
                  var mychars = $('#message').val().length; 
                  var mysms = Math.ceil(mychars / 160);

                           console.log (mysms); 
                           console.log (mychars +'' + ' characters'); 
           });
      });
```