# international Count sms characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, internationalization, sms

I found [Count characters/sms using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705185/count-characters-sms-using-jQuery), but it does not support international characters such as Chinese, Japanese, Thai, etc.

```
var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
    $messages = $remaining.next();

$('#message').keyup(function(){
    var chars = this.value.length,
        messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160),
        remaining = messages * 160 - (chars % (messages * 160) || messages * 160);

    $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
    $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
});
```

Here are some examples of incorrect character counts:

> 您好，請問你吃飯了嗎？ << 11 characters
>
> สวัสดีคุณกินหรือ? << 17 characters
>
> こんにちは、あなたは食べていますか？ << 18 characters
>
> 안녕하세요, 당신이 먹는 거죠? << 17 characters
>
> हैलो, आप खाते हैं? << 18 characters
>
> Добры дзень, вы ясьце? << 22 characters

How can I make this work with non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Seems to count just fine for the most part. `您好，請問你吃飯了嗎？` *is* 11 characters long, and the numbers for Japanese, Korean and Russian are fine as well. What numbers would you be expecting? Only Thai and Hindi may be off, but I don't know how characters are counted there.

Comment: Yes, as you said Thai and Hindi is diference, ดี is already 2 characters, so, as above jquery i found, how to make it support international chinese, thai, japanese, korean, hindi, russian..

Comment: Yes, but "您" is *one UTF-8 character*. Apparently you want to count *bytes*, not characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really count in "characters" here. According to the [SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Message_size) article on Wikipedia one of three different encodings are used for SMS (7-bit GSM, 8-bit GSM and UTF-16). So first you'll need to know/decide which encoding you'll be using.

If you know you'll always be using UTF-16, then you can count the number of [16-bit code units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description) a string will take up. A standard SMS can consist of 70 16-bit code units. But this will limit messages in Latin characters to 70, too. So if you want to use the full 160 characters (with 7-bit encoding) or 140 characters (with 8-bit encoding) for Latin characters, then you'll need to distinguish between the three cases.

Example for counting UTF-16 16-bit code units:

```
var message = "您好，請問你吃飯了嗎？";

var utf16codeUnits = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = message.length; i < len; i++) {
  utf16codeUnits += message.charCodeAt(i) < 0x10000 ? 1 : 2;
}
```

BTW, this **will** come up with then same numbers you posted as "incorrect", so you'll need to explain why you consider them incorrect.

---

**EDIT**

Despite being accepted already I quickly hacked up a function that correctly (as far as I can say) calculates the GSM 7-bit (if possible) and UTF-16 sizes of a SMS message: http://jsfiddle.net/puKJb/

Comment: How about using `Math.ceil(Math.log(message.charCodeAt(i))/Math.log(2<<bits))` with `bits` is either `7` or `8` instead?

Comment: @Gumbo: I don't think that applies here. The GSM 7 and 8-bit encoding isn't based on Unicode code point (which `charCodeAt`  returns).

Comment: I *think* the [SMS standard](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/23038.htm) specifies UCS-2 rather than UTF-16. So 2-byte characters only, and no characters outside the BMP.

Comment: @RoToRa in the jsfiddle code, the gsm7bitUnits doesn't work for accented characters like "á" which are common in the spanish language.

Comment: @RoToRa just investigated more and found that characters like "á" are non-GSM and so the max length of an SMS message containing them is 70 and those characters are counted as 1 unit.

Comment: @RoToRa In the JS snippet can you explain the logic behind utf16codeUnits += message.charCodeAt(i) < 0x10000 ? 1 : 2;

Comment: @adsun UTF-16 encodes characters either with one unit (= 2 bytes = 16 bits) or two units (= 4 bytes = 32 bits). All characters up to code point 0x10000 use one unit and all other charcters with a higher codepoint use two units.