# Splitting an SMS Message that includes "escaped charatcers"

Tags: php, regex, sms

I am needing the split an SMS message over 160 characters into multiple parts so I can send large messages.

Some SMS API's do the splitting for you (they support multipart messages) but I am working with a couple of companies that don't so I have to split the messages myself.

Splitting the message is easy. My issue was what do I do when the SMS message contains characters that are "escaped" and "use up" 2 characters?

For those who have no idea what I am talking about:

> Even in the 7-bit encoding, a few characters are "escaped" which means they "use up" 2 characters. In the default 7-bit encoding, these are: `{}[]\|^~€`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061794/158126

So for example, this string is **35 characters long**:

> The amount of this payment is €100.

However, when sent through the SMS provider, it is actually **36 characters long** because of the Euro sign which is "escaped" and takes up two characters.

There have been a number of questions about splitting SMS messages but none of them take into account the fact that these few "escaped" characters could cause problems.

So I have created a function to combat this. I have tested this and it has worked so hopefully it might help someone else.

To get back to the point of my question, I feel my code is very inefficient. I am running `preg_match` several times and within loops and I'm not sure of a better solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this code more efficient?

```
function sms_message_parts($message) {

    // Message parts
    $parts = array();

    // The default encoding is utf16 (unicode) until proven otherwise
    $encoding = 'utf16';

    // Characters that are allowed in 7bit messages
    $gsm_7bit_chars = '@£$¥èéùìòÇ\nØø\rÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞÆæßÉ !"#¤%&\'\(\)\*+,-\.\/0123456789:;<=>?¡ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÑÜ§¿abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöñüà';

    // Characters that are allowed in 7bit_ex messages
    $gsm_7bit_ex_chars = '\^{}\\\\\[~\]|€';

    // Message lengths
    $message_lengths = array(
        '7bit' => 160,
        '7bit_ex' => 160,
        'utf16' => 70
    );

    // Detect encoding of message
    if (preg_match("/^[" . $gsm_7bit_chars . "]*$/u", $message) == 1)
        $encoding = '7bit';
    elseif (preg_match("/^[" . $gsm_7bit_chars . $gsm_7bit_ex_chars . "]*$/u", $message) == 1)
        $encoding = '7bit_ex';

    // Determine how long each part of the message can be
    $max_parts_length = $message_lengths[$encoding];

    // Length of the message
    $message_length = mb_strlen($message, 'UTF-8');

    // 7bit_ex message
    // Escaped characters found so we need to find the REAL length
    // and split the message differently
    if ($encoding == '7bit_ex') {

        // Count how many extra characters are required a result of
        // the 7bit_ex characters
        $extra_chars = 0;
        for($i=0;$i<$message_length;$i++) {
            if (preg_match("/^[" . $gsm_7bit_ex_chars . "]*$/u", mb_substr($message, $i, 1, 'UTF-8')) == 1)
                $extra_chars++;
        }

        // New message length
        $new_message_length = $message_length + $extra_chars;

        // Is this going to be a multipart message?
        if ($new_message_length > $max_parts_length) {

            // Split the message
            $start = 0;
            while(true) {

                // Determine the length of the split (if it's the last part, we don't need to look for
                // extra "escaped" characters)
                $last_part = false;
                $chars_left = $message_length - $start;
                if ($chars_left < $max_parts_length) {
                    $split_length = $chars_left;
                    $last_part = true;
                } else {
                    $split_length = $max_parts_length;
                }

                // Extract the message part
                $part = mb_substr($message, $start, $split_length, 'UTF-8');

                // Check to see if this part has any escaped characters
                $part_extra_chars = 0;
                if (!$last_part) {
                    for($i=0;$i<$split_length;$i++) {
                        if (preg_match("/^[" . $gsm_7bit_ex_chars . "]*$/u", mb_substr($part, $i, 1, 'UTF-8')) == 1)
                            $part_extra_chars++;
                    }
                }

                // If it has escaped characters, deduct from the amount of characters in this part
                // before adding to the parts array
                if ($part_extra_chars > 0) {

                    $part = mb_substr($message, $start, ($split_length - $part_extra_chars), 'UTF-8');
                    $parts[] = trim($part);
                    $start = $start + ($split_length - $part_extra_chars);

                // No escaped characters, add part to parts array
                } else {

                    $parts[] = trim($part) . ' ' .$split_length;
                    $start = $start + $max_parts_length;

                }

                // We've reached the end of the message
                if ($start >= $message_length)
                    break;

            }

        // It's a signle message
        } else {
            $parts[] = $message;
        }

    // 7bit and utf16 (unicode) messages don't have escaped characters
    } else {

        // Is this going to be a multipart message? Split this part before adding to the
        // parts array
        if ($message_length > $max_parts_length) {

            // Split the message into parts
            $total_messages = ceil($message_length / $max_parts_length);
            $start = 0;
            for($i=0;$i<$total_messages;$i++) {
                $parts[] = trim(mb_substr($message, $start, $max_parts_length, 'UTF-8'));
                $start = $start + $max_parts_length;
            }

        // It's a signle message
        } else {
            $parts[] = $message;
        }

    }

    return array('parts' => $parts, 'encoding' => $encoding);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to skip particular charcater then you can use regex.

something like : `(?#comment)`

Everything between (?# and ) is ignored by the regex engine.

Or you can use regex with `replace_all` where you can replace character you want with no char i.e. `''`