# SMS Character Count

Tags: jquery

How to create n number of sms counts using jquery?

Like this code only 3 sms count. I need N number of sms count using like this same code.
How to do?

```
$('#smsText').smsArea();
```

The HTML:

```
<b id="smsCount"></b> SMS (<b id="smsLength"></b>) Characters left
<textarea id="smsText"></textarea>
```

```
(function($){
    $.fn.smsArea = function(options){

    var
    e = this,
    cutStrLength = 0,

    s = $.extend({

        cut: true,
        maxSmsNum: 3,
        interval: 400,

        counters: {
            message: $('#smsCount'),
            character: $('#smsLength')
        },

        lengths: {
            ascii: [160, 306, 459],
            unicode: [70, 134, 201]
        }
    }, options);


    e.keyup(function(){

        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
   var
            smsType,
            smsLength = 0,
            smsCount = -1,
            charsLeft = 0,
            text = e.val(),
            isUnicode = false;

            for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                switch(text[charPos]){
                    case "\n": 
                    case "[":
                    case "]":
                    case "\\":
                    case "^":
                    case "{":
                    case "}":
                    case "|":
                    case "€":
                        smsLength += 2;
                    break;

                    default:
                        smsLength += 1;
                }


                if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€") isUnicode = true;
            }

            if(isUnicode){
                smsType = s.lengths.unicode;

            }else{
                smsType = s.lengths.ascii;
            }

            for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                cutStrLength = smsType[sCount];
                if(smsLength <= smsType[sCount]){

                    smsCount = sCount + 1;
                    charsLeft = smsType[sCount] - smsLength;
                    break
                }
            }

            if(s.cut) e.val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
            smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);

            s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
            s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);

        }, s.interval)
    }).keyup()
}}(jQuery));
```

I tried SMS character Counts. But this code only 3 sms counts. I Need n number of sms counts. Like create more than 100 or 200 sms. If any one know means send the query.

Comment: You have to show us what you have tried in order to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, the author give arrays with max lengths for only 3 sms :

```
lengths: {
    ascii: [160, 306, 459],
    unicode: [70, 134, 201]
}
```

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705185/count-characters-sms-using-jquery), it's calculated like this :

- one normal ASCII sms will have 160 available characters
- if you pass to 2 sms, a particular header is required for sending 2 sms as 1 message (the UDH, i think). This header requires 7 characters for each sms. So, 2 sms have (160 - 7) + (160 - 7) = 153 + 153 = 306 available characters
- Same mechanism for unicode, but max length is 70 and UDH takes 3 characters

So you have to develop a function which calculate this max of available characters for a given number of sms, i propose :

```
function calculateSmsMaxLength (isUnicode, writtenSmsNb) {

                if (isUnicode) {
                    if (writtenSmsNb == 0) {
                        return 70;
                    } else {
                        return (70 * (writtenSmsNb + 1)) - ((writtenSmsNb + 1) * 3);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (writtenSmsNb == 0) {
                        return 160;
                    } else {
                        return (160 * (writtenSmsNb + 1)) - ((writtenSmsNb + 1) * 7);
                    }
                }
            }
```

isUnicode : true or false, depending on the content of the sms

writtenSmsNb : the number of sms you want to calculate the max available characters for.

Finally, this is the code for... mmmh, lets say 5 max sms :

```
(function($){
$.fn.smsArea = function(options){

    var e = this,
        cutStrLength = 0,

        s = $.extend({

            cut: true,
            maxSmsNum: 5,
            interval: 400,

            counters: {
                message: $('#smsCount'),
                character: $('#smsLength')
            },

            calculateSmsMaxLength : function (isUnicode, writtenSmsNb) {

                if (isUnicode) {
                    if (writtenSmsNb == 0) {
                        return 70;
                    } else {
                        return (70 * (writtenSmsNb + 1)) - ((writtenSmsNb + 1) * 3);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (writtenSmsNb == 0) {
                        return 160;
                    } else {
                        return (160 * (writtenSmsNb + 1)) - ((writtenSmsNb + 1) * 7);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, options);


    e.keyup(function(){

        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(function(){

            var smsType,
                smsLength = 0,
                smsCount = -1,
                charsLeft = 0,
                text = e.val(),
                isUnicode = false;

            for(var charPos = 0; charPos < text.length; charPos++){
                switch(text[charPos]){
                    case "\n": case "[": case "]": case "\\": case "^": case "{": case "}": case "|": case "€":
                        smsLength += 2;
                    break;

                    default:
                        smsLength += 1;
                }

                if(text.charCodeAt(charPos) > 127 && text[charPos] != "€")
                    isUnicode = true;
            }

            for(var sCount = 0; sCount < s.maxSmsNum; sCount++){

                smsType = s.calculateSmsMaxLength(isUnicode, sCount);
                cutStrLength = smsType;
                if(smsLength <= smsType){

                    smsCount = sCount + 1;
                    charsLeft = smsType - smsLength;
                    break
                }
            }

            if(s.cut) e.val(text.substring(0, cutStrLength));
            smsCount == -1 && (smsCount = s.maxSmsNum, charsLeft = 0);

            s.counters.message.html(smsCount);
            s.counters.character.html(charsLeft);

        }, s.interval)
    }).keyup();

}}(jQuery));


//Start
$(function(){
    $('#smsText').smsArea({maxSmsNum:5});
})
```

Just change the both "maxSmsNum" values to set the max sms you want to allow. For information, the max is 255 in theory, but in reality, it's often 6 to 8 sms max by sending.