# I am using smsArea() function that is count text on keyup event, but how to count that text when value is append through jq?

Tags: jquery

I am using this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955596/7544946

My Html

```
    <div>
        <span id="smsLength"></span>&nbsp chars. left<span>&nbsp of msg</span>
        <span id="smsCount"></span>
        <textarea style="width:100%" rows="5" name="message" value="" id="smsText"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p id="msg">Hello</p> 
    <button type="button" id="copy_msg">Copy</button>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
    $("#copy_msg").on("click", function(){
      var msg = $("#msg").html();
      $("#smsText").val(msg);
    });
```

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#smsText').smsArea();
    </script>
```

Want to count that character when value is append.
I tried keyup event like this

```
$("#smsText").trigger('keyup');
```

```
$("#smsText").keyup();
```

but nothing worked.Any ideas?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vrunda22/95h61q37/

Comment: can you provide some detail, in order to answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It seems you question will need some adjustments to help you get the best support the community can offer.
Please look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) links. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: `$("#copy_msg").on("click", function(){var msg = "Hello";$("#smsText").val(msg);$("#smsText").keyup();});`

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar I already tried this.but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trigger event when value is changed:

```js
$("#copy_msg").on("click", function(){
  var msg = $("#msg").html();
  $("#smsText").val(msg);
  $("#smsText").keyup();
}); 
$('body').on('keyup','textarea', function(){
 console.log(160-$(this).val().toString().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span id="smsLength"></span>&nbsp chars. left<span>&nbsp of msg</span>
    <span id="smsCount"></span>
    <textarea style="width:100%" rows="5" name="message" value="" id="smsText"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<p id="msg">Hello</p> 
<button type="button" id="copy_msg">Copy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thaks!! It work nice here..but I want character count like SMS. It seems different.

Comment: Yes, i just given example. You should modify your code. Or open new question for that